# How to know when all asynchronous callbacks have been executed?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

I'm iterating over a list of URLs in an array and for each URL I'm downloading the entire page.

```
var urlInformations = [];
var count = 0;
urls.forEach(function(url) {
    // download and add to urlInformations
    count++
    if (count == urls.length) {
        // do something after all URLs are processed
    }
});
```

Right now the way I'm handling this is by maintaining a count of elements, increment it in the anonymous function and at the end of that function if the count reaches the number of URLs I have I would do what I need. There could be race condition and concurrency issues here, right? How should this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Javascript is single-threaded, which means if you increment a counter and then compare it against some number to determine whether or not to continue, you've basically just implemented a semaphore.  There won't be concurrency issues doing this.

Comment: I suppose then, since alert call blocks execution, what if an event occurs while alert dialog is open? My guess is the event is pushed to stack. Am I right?

Comment: @goldenparrot: almost, not a stack, but a queue. Once alert is closed, JavaScript engine will start handling all queued events one by one. BTW +1 for *just2n*

Answer (score 0):

```
(XMLHttpRequest).addEventListener('load', handleload, false);

function handleload(e) {
    //dostuff
}
```

The load event of an XMLHttpRequest fires when it finishes loading; is that what you're after?